# Java crash ! NTDLL.DLL when using jni and jpeg62.dll

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvm-crash, phash

Been trying to run pHash on java using jni and i have faced so many problems and solved them and now i am stuck at this place. i fixed all my dlls and my source code and everything is fine but when i try to run my java code using the dlls... JAVA CRASHES when using jpeg62.dll because im trying to analyze a jpg image using DCT image hash..

i need to know what does ntdll.dll+0x1b1fa have and why does it crash. from this report i didnt understand much because im yet a beginner at programming. if any expert can please assist me or guide me or just give me hints of where to look for the bug that would be very much appreciated.

p.s: i use jpeg62.dll, zlib.h, libpng.dll as dependencies for my pHash.dll and they were already there so i havent done anything to them.

---

here is my log:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7c92b1fa, pid=2764, tid=4492

 JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [ntdll.dll+0x1b1fa]

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x003a6800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4492, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000010

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000e78, EDX=0x10311478
ESP=0x008eaf70, EBP=0x008eafe4, ESI=0x10311468, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x7c92b1fa, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x008eaf70)
0x008eaf70:   02dd40d8 008f744c 02dd40d8 008eb020
0x008eaf80:   77c04045 00000000 00000001 02dd0178
0x008eaf90:   00000007 0000031d 00000007 0050004a
0x008eafa0:   00470045 0045004d 77c0004d 00440050
0x008eafb0:   02dd0178 00450052 000000e0 00000007
0x008eafc0:   02dd2c2c 02dd3121 008eaf9c 00000007
0x008eafd0:   00000000 02dd4708 00000003 00000000
0x008eafe0:   00000e78 008eaff8 7c911046 00311468 

Instructions: (pc=0x7c92b1fa)
0x7c92b1ea:   8b 46 10 3b c3 89 45 fc 0f 84 9e 00 00 00 8b 06
0x7c92b1fa:   ff 40 10 8b 45 fc 83 e0 01 89 45 e8 8b 06 ff 40 


Stack: [0x008c0000,0x00910000],  sp=0x008eaf70,  free space=171k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x1b1fa]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x1046]
C  [msvcrt.dll+0x3120f]
C  [jpeg62.dll+0xcb94]
C  [PhashTest.dll+0x5be21]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.phash.pHash.dctImageHash(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/phash/DCTImageHash;+0
j  org.phash.pHash.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x02aa5c00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5332, stack(0x02d20000,0x02d70000)]
  0x02aa2c00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2800, stack(0x02cd0000,0x02d20000)]
  0x02aa1400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4328, stack(0x02c80000,0x02cd0000)]
  0x02aa0000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3988, stack(0x02c30000,0x02c80000)]
  0x02a61400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1016, stack(0x02be0000,0x02c30000)]
  0x02a5cc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5088, stack(0x02b90000,0x02be0000)]
=>0x003a6800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4492, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02a5b000 VMThread [stack: 0x02b40000,0x02b90000] [id=3700]
  0x02aa7400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02d70000,0x02dc0000] [id=4864]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 960K, used 219K [0x22990000, 0x22a90000, 0x22e70000)
  eden space 896K,  24% used [0x22990000, 0x229c6c50, 0x22a70000)
  from space 64K,   0% used [0x22a70000, 0x22a70000, 0x22a80000)
  to   space 64K,   0% used [0x22a80000, 0x22a80000, 0x22a90000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 0K [0x22e70000, 0x23270000, 0x26990000)
   the space 4096K,   0% used [0x22e70000, 0x22e70000, 0x22e70200, 0x23270000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 26K [0x26990000, 0x27590000, 0x2a990000)
   the space 12288K,   0% used [0x26990000, 0x26996830, 0x26996a00, 0x27590000)
    ro space 8192K,  67% used [0x2a990000, 0x2aef9040, 0x2aef9200, 0x2b190000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x2b190000, 0x2b80d348, 0x2b80d400, 0x2bd90000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c910000 - 0x7c9c6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c908000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77e4a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e50000 - 0x77ee2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fc0000 - 0x77fd1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e360000 - 0x7e3f1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77ef0000 - 0x77f39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76330000 - 0x7634d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8b0000 - 0x6db3b000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76af0000 - 0x76b1e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d860000 - 0x6d86c000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3e0000 - 0x6d3ff000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d340000 - 0x6d348000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bb0000 - 0x76bbb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6d8af000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x10000000 - 0x100ca000     C:\MyProjects\Phash\PhashTest.dll
0x6cc40000 - 0x6cc84000     C:\MyProjects\Phash\libpng12.dll
0x62e80000 - 0x62e9f000     C:\MyProjects\Phash\zlib1.dll
0x77be0000 - 0x77c38000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x686c0000 - 0x686e4000     C:\MyProjects\Phash\jpeg62.dll
0x7e670000 - 0x7ee91000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x77f40000 - 0x77fb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x10200000 - 0x10323000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_597c3456\MSVCR90D.dll
0x773a0000 - 0x774a3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.5512_x-ww_35d4ce83\comctl32.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: org.phash.pHash
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Programme/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Programme/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/../jre/bin;C:\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_2\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_2\jre\1.4.2\bin\client;C:\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_2\jre\1.4.2\bin;C:\programme\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\bin;C:\programme\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\jre\1.4.2\bin\client;C:\programme\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\jre\1.4.2\bin;c:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Programme\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Programme\V3PA3\v3iaxa1\bin\Jetform;C:\Programme\SER\OCRPDFTool
USERNAME=scan
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2097151k(1422692k free), swap 4194303k(3192776k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_16-b01), built on Jul 31 2009 11:26:58 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Mon Sep 09 09:46:53 2013
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Moved answer out of question)</sub>

ALL DLLS should be in the directory of the java jni project along with the .ilk .exp .pdb files generated from the build file! they are very important.. without them your dependencies that support your main dll will NOT work ! i really hope this is helpful to anyone out there using jni. also notice:if java crashes with ntdll.dll then you are missing something